# dbeaver inline where query

Tags: sql, dbeaver

how to format where query in dbeaver? i know that this entry exists because i copied the id from the table.

[image]

Comment: Use single quotes for string literals, like `'ck9mddjdj'`. (Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, and you don't have a column named ck9mddjdj...)

Comment: Please write code and error like text.